# Turning a Google apps script library into ... an extension?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

I've got a GA script library, which contains some Google Docs operations that I use a lot (such as specific formatting, heading numbers or specific searches). When I want to use these functions, I currently add a script to the document, that loads the menu builder (in the library), and then add the library to that script. That seems to be the shortest way of using the library across multiple files. I have these questions:

(1) Is there a way in which these library functions can be available to all my Google Docs, without having to load them per document? My understanding is that this is not possible.

(2) Is this correct: The best way to make these library functions available would be to build an extension, and publish this on the Chrome store. (Possibly as 'beta extension'?)

If this is correct, then could somebody point me to a simple step-by-step guide for turning scripts into docs extensions? I've looked around, but what I saw wasn't all that clear. Ideally I'd like to be able to update the extension frequently, as it's still under development.

Thanks!

Comment: Add-on, not extension. And official documentation has step-by-step guides for this.

Comment: Agree with @tehhowch, adding the [link to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used the information here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish